# How to remove WMS from semantic in sesssion description?

Tags: mqtt, sdp, webrtc-android

I am using MQTT with `Webrtc`, I have to pass a specific SDP object to the server. I don't know why WMS gets added to my semantics . Can anyone have proper idea of what it stands for and How to remove it?

Instead of this

```
SEMANTICS : **WMS** Stream
```

I want

```
SEMANTICS:  Stream
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is sending this in its SDP because it implemented a early version of https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-mmusic-msid-16. The wms-semantic attribute is gone from the specification and might go away so do not rely on it.